# Trouble connecting a aws ec2 ubuntu 16.04 instance to internet from private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2

Im seeing an odd issue with an ubuntu 16.04 instance in AWS. I spun it up in a private subnet and it is unable to connect to the internet. I can sshe to it just fine from my bastion in the public subnet but can not ping or curl anything from the instance. Im wondering if there is now a step to enable this in AWS that I have missed out on somehow. I have a working amazon linux ec2 instance sitting right beside it in the same subnet with the same security group, same keys, same nat gateway, same everything except OS. It can curl or ping all day long and its fine. Both instances are private ip only.

Is there something i need to specifically now do in Ubuntu to enable internet access????

AMI im using for the ubuntu instance: ami-43a15f3e

Thanks

Comment: This really sounds like a routing problem. I know you said "same subnet," which means same routing tables, but are you 100% sure of that? Also, can you connect to the other instance from the Ubuntu instance using its private IP?

Comment: And yea, I double checked that they are in the same subnet/routing table.

Comment: After more digging and talking to others on the net it sounds like a bug in the ami so im reporting to AWS. I spun up debian and rhel instances all in the same subnet as well and they all worked out of the box. Also tried that ubuntu ami in a public subnet and it couldnt get to the internet either.

Comment: After working AWS for a bit we figured out that the /etc/resolv.conf file had been altered based on my DHCP options. Meanwhile the equivalent  files in the AMZN and RHEL instances were not changed. He had no explanation as to why. I set my DHCP options to not include my domain and it started working as expected.